# why table name changed to uppercase automatically in linux when exec with raw sql use go-gorm

Tags: go-gorm

why table name changed to uppercase automatically in linux when exec with raw sql use go-gorm,but in windows it works normally.

environment：
mysql8.0, centos7.6, go1.16, github.com/jinzhu/gorm 1.9

```
db.Debug().Exec("insert into t_if_user
```

error log:

```
Error 1146: Table 'gridtradingdb.T_IF_USER' doesn't exist
```

How can I fix this problem.
Help appreciated.

Comment: Does that table exist? Afaik, in mysql names are case-insensitive on Windows and stored in lowercase by default, but there system variable that changes it

Answer (score 0):

From [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html#:%7E:text=Table%20names%20are%20stored%20in,database%20names%20and%20table%20aliases.)

> How table and database names are stored on disk and used in MySQL is
> affected by the lower_case_table_names system variable.
> lower_case_table_names can take the values shown in the following
> table. This variable does not affect case sensitivity of trigger
> identifiers. ***On Unix, the default value of lower_case_table_names is***
> ***0.*** On Windows, the default value is 1. On macOS, the default value is 2.

Value 0:

> Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase
> specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. Name
> comparisons ***are case-sensitive***. You should not set this variable to 0
> if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file
> names (such as Windows or macOS). If you force this variable to 0 with
> --lower-case-table-names=0 on a case-insensitive file system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption
> may result.